# AWS cli/sam-local package env.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am using [aws-sam-local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local) to write, test and deploy some Lambda functions.

Using the `-env-var` option I can pass env.json when testing locally, so my lambdas get properties I don't have to source control.

How do I publish these values? The aws-sam-local cli seems to sit ontop of the main aws cli, and I see a `--parameter-override` option, but that only takes a key=value string.

Is it possible to pass the file to override? If not, how do I format the string for env vars for different lambdas?

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a way to pass the env vars as a parameters file similar to --parameters in cloudformation create-stack, this is an open issue github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2828 and github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/111